# Javac symbol not found error , after importing java.nio

Tags: import, javac, java-io, java.nio.file

so , i am making this program as an exercise in order to learn java,

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io;
import java.nio;

class wordsInLine {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    int wordCount;

    //checking for correct syntax
    if (args.length > 1){
        System.out.println("Usage : java wordsInLine [path to text file to scan for words, ommit if you want to be asked for input]");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //if the user has provided a path to a text file then read the file
    if (args.length == 1) {
        Path file = args[0];
        byte[] fileBytes; 
        fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file);

        //convert the text of the file to a big string
        String line = new String(fileBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    }else{ // else the user wants to give us his/her own line

         //getting the users's input
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         String line = input.nextLine();
    }

    //call the word count function
    wordCount = countWords(line);

    //print result
    System.out.println(wordCount + " words found in the input line");
}


public static int countWords(String line){

    //vars for easier understanding and reading
    final boolean IN = true;
    final boolean OUT = false;
    boolean isLetter;
    boolean STATE = false;

    //just counting the words here
    int wordCount = 0;

    //looping through every character of the user's input line
    for (int i = 0, n = line.length(); i < n; i++){
        isLetter = Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i));

        if (isLetter == true){
            STATE = IN;
        }

        if ((STATE == IN) && (isLetter == false)){
                wordCount++;     
                STATE = OUT;
        }

        if (((STATE == IN) && (line.charAt(i) == '\n')) || ((STATE == IN) && (i == (line.length() - 1)))){
            wordCount++;
            STATE = OUT;
        }
    }

    return wordCount;
}
```

}

i try to compile this using `javac wordsInLine.java`
and i get 
`wordsInLine.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
import java.io;
           ^
  symbol:   class io
  location: package java
wordsInLine.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import java.nio;
           ^
  symbol:   class nio
  location: package java
wordsInLine.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
            Path file = args[0];
            ^
  symbol:   class Path
  location: class wordsInLine
wordsInLine.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
            fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file);
                        ^
  symbol:   variable Files
  location: class wordsInLine
wordsInLine.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
            String line = new String(fileBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                                                ^
  symbol:   variable StandardCharsets
  location: class wordsInLine
5 errors`

the 2nd and 3rd import statements i found online , if i omit them and i try to compile i get

```
wordsInLine.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        Path file = args[0];
        ^
symbol:   class Path
location: class wordsInLine
wordsInLine.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file);
                    ^
symbol:   variable Files
location: class wordsInLine
wordsInLine.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        String line = new String(fileBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                                            ^
symbol:   variable StandardCharsets
location: class wordsInLine
```

i googled and a lot of people said that i maybe have an outdated java and/or javac version ,

```
java -version
```

returns

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

also

```
javac -version
```

returns

```
javac 1.8.0_101
```

I just started learning java and i've hit a brick wall, 
can someone tell me what am i missing here ?

**EDIT: after changing the 2nd and 3rd import statements (suggested by @EJP) i get:**

```
wordsInLine.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        Path file = args[0];
        ^
symbol:   class Path
location: class wordsInLine
wordsInLine.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file);
                    ^
symbol:   variable Files
location: class wordsInLine
wordsInLine.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        String line = new String(fileBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                                            ^
symbol:   variable StandardCharsets
location: class wordsInLine
3 errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io;
import java.nio;
```

Neither of these statements is legal Java. You need

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
```

or better still use your IDE features to do the imports for you.

Comment: I tried it and it worked, i don't get symbol not found errors on the import statements but i get them on Path , Files , and  StandardCharsets.UTF_8. Check the bottom of my question for more details . Also how come import `java.util.Scanner;` is valid but `import java.io;` is not?

Comment: So you need to do what I said in the last line of my answer. There's really no reason to be typing import statements yourself in 2016. The answer to your final question is rather trivial Java and is found in the JLS.